# Highlight text while not damaging user scan

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, usability-testing, text

I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to highlight text while keeping it scannable.

As you can see from the illustration below, the text is already bold. I'm trying to understand what would be the correct way to emphasise the word *"Mute"*. I've tried several tryouts, but none of them where good enough.

**Note:
The reason why I need those words to highlight even more is because I'm using this screenshots at the App Store. Where the users usually sees them at the Search Results at a lot more scaled down version.**

**What would you recommend for correct highlight? Thank you!**

**Illustration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should highlight here. It only reduces the legibility (lower contrast) while not grabbing more attention; it is the only text.

Comment: Hey PixelSnaer, thank for replying. Putting it just plain black on white looks to0 "dead". That's why there is a light background behind the all text as shown in tryout 1. What if the background is necessary, what are my options than? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you bold everything, it's as if nothing is bold. Think about setting your type in roman and bolding the bit you want to emphasize. Plenty of roman font faces are readable at small sizes.